# How can I create Outlook calendar entries that are linked to contacts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In Act!, users can create calendar alerts that are bound to specific contacts. I would like to accomplish this in Outlook 2007. That is, when I am viewing a specific Outlook contact, I want to have the ability to instantly create an event in the calendar that is automatically linked to the contact. When I click on that event, I should see the contact's info/details. How can I do this?